# Join a new column by a condition

Tags: mysql

How can I join a new column in my query by condition? I have 3 tables:

> Users table:

```
userid     name
1          John
2          Joe
3          Sam
4          Alex
```

> Questions table:

```
userid     questionid     asked
1          1              2011-11-11 22:52
1          2              2011-11-11 22:52
3          3              2011-11-11 22:52
2          4              2011-11-11 22:52
```

> Like table:

```
userid     questionid
1          1
1          2
1          3
1          4
```

I'd like to query a question of a user and determine whether the user liked the question or not. The result should be if the user liked the question:

```
userid     questionid     liked
1          1              1
```

Other case when the user didn't like the question:

```
userid     questionid     liked
2          1              0
```

Conrete code I'm using now: (a bit different fieldnames)

```
SELECT temp.`id`, temp.`userid`, `categories`.`name`, `user`.`username`, temp.`title`,
    temp.`details`, temp.`date` FROM (
    SELECT `id`, `categoryid`, `details`, `title`, `userid`, `date`, @a := id, if(@a = ". $position .", @b := 1, @b) AS join_id
    FROM `questions`
    join(SELECT @a := 0, @b := 0) t
    ORDER BY `date` DESC
    ) as temp
    LEFT JOIN `user`
    ON temp.`userid` = `user`.`userid`
    LEFT JOIN `categories`
    ON temp.`categoryid` = `categories`.`categoryid`
    WHERE join_id = 1
    LIMIT 1,5;
```

Position means the id to query from. ATM userid 31 has only liked questions. SQLfiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fe17/2

Comment: What about a case statement?

Comment: Show us the query you have please.

Comment: you can do multiple inner join between those tables..all of them on the field UserID, and then to set the like field to 1 or 0

Comment: Not clear, you mean to find out all the likes by different users on a question or the likes by user himself on its own question ? And same in otherway meaning user who did not like his/her own question ?

Comment: You don't join columns: you join tables; you select columns.

Comment: When I said join I meant create a new column and add it when query. That column would be 'liked'. There is my sql and a sqlfidle link for the structure of my tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a left (outer) join to join the `Like` table to the `Question` table. 
For each match `Like.userid` (and `Like.questionid`) will be `not null`, else `null`. 
You can check this in the select column with the `IF()` function:

```
SELECT userid, questionid, if(Questions.userid is null, 0, 1) as liked 
FROM Questions 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Like ON Questions.userid = Like.userid and Questions.questionid = Like.questionid;
```

This lists all questions a user was asked. You can just narrow it down to one user and one question by adding a `WHERE` clause.

(Note that LIKE is a keyword in MySQL. You should choose another table name or quote/escape the table name in your statement).

Comment: I've already solved it but if I haven't, your answer would've been the best so you got the point :) Thank you for your help!